# QT add Map QML Items via C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtlocation

I try to add QML map items like MapQuickItem or MapCircle from C++ to my map.
Unfortunately, they don't show up on the map. The same code with just a QML rectangle works. 
rect v1 is the rectangle for testing which works. rect v2 is the mapCircle which doesn't work.
When I add my circle QML code 1:1 into my map QML code it works fine.

**main.cpp**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/map.qml"));

    QQmlComponent compRect (view->engine(), QUrl("qrc:/rect.qml"));

    view->setWidth(1000);
    view->setHeight(650);
    view->setTitle("GUI");


    QQuickItem *map = view->findChild<QQuickItem*>("map1");

    QQuickItem *rect = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(compRect.create(view->rootContext()));

    rect->setParentItem(map);
    rect->setParent(map); //know this is not for visual objects, just for test

    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**rect.qml v1**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtLocation 5.14
import QtPositioning 5.14

Rectangle
{
        color: "grey"
        opacity: .8

        width: 100
        height: 100
        radius: 4
        Text
        {
            id: text
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "hi"
            color: "orangered"
            font.weight: Font.Bold
        }
}
```

**rect.qml v2**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtLocation 5.14
import QtPositioning 5.14

MapCircle 
{
    center 
    {
        latitude: 47.5
        longitude: 8.9
    }
    radius: 5000.0
    color: 'green'
    border.width: 3
}
```

**map.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtPositioning 5.14
import QtLocation 5.14

Map
{
    objectName: "map1"
    id: map_map
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: Plugin
    {
        name: "mapboxgl" // "osm", "esri", ...
    }
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(47.6,9.5)
    zoomLevel: 8

    // get position of device and set map center to it
    PositionSource
    {
        active: true
        onPositionChanged:
        {
            map.center(position.coordinate)
            console.log(position.coordinate)
        }
    }

    Timer
    {
        id: timerReload
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true

        onTriggered:
        {
            controller.triggerReload();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The worst thing you can do in QML that creating QML items in C++. The ideal situation is when everything is done in QML. If you want to extend the functionality you always can use plugins/custom items. That what you try to do is a sign of an incorrect application architecture.

Comment: So If I need to drag an element from a `QTreeWidget` to a Map I should not do it by using C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That it is established that an item is a child of the map does not imply that it is shown on the map, if you want to add an item you must use the [`addMapItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#addMapItem-method) method and in C++ you can use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) to invoke that method but you need to access the type `QDeclarativeGeoMapItemBase` that belongs to the private Qt API, considering the above the solution is:

***.pro**

```
QT += quick location location-private
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQuickView>

#include <QtLocation/private/qdeclarativegeomapitembase_p.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/map.qml"));
    view.resize(1000, 650);
    view.setTitle("GUI");
    view.show();
    if(QQuickItem *map = view.findChild<QQuickItem*>("map1")){
        QQmlComponent component(view.engine(), QUrl("qrc:/rect.qml"));
        if(QDeclarativeGeoMapItemBase *rect = qobject_cast<QDeclarativeGeoMapItemBase*>(component.create(view.rootContext()))){
            bool status = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(map,
                                      "addMapItem",
                                      Qt::DirectConnection,
                                      Q_ARG(QDeclarativeGeoMapItemBase*, rect));
            Q_ASSERT(status);
        }
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

The problem with the previous method is that it is dangerous since the map or any QML element can be removed at any time so that it could generate a problem, in addition it limits the modification of QML and finally it is necessary to access the private Qt API That can change without notice. Therefore I will offer better alternatives:

- Use a QObject and export it to QML where items are created and added to the map:

  ```cpp
  #include <QGuiApplication>
  #include <QQuickView>
  #include <QGeoCoordinate>
  #include <QQmlContext>

  class Helper: public QObject{
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      void addCircle(const QGeoCoordinate & coordinate){
          Q_EMIT circleSignal(coordinate);
      }
  Q_SIGNALS:
      void circleSignal(const QGeoCoordinate & coordinate);
  };

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
      QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
      QQuickView view;
      Helper helper;
      view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("helper", &helper);
      view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/map.qml"));
      view.resize(1000, 650);
      view.setTitle("GUI");
      view.show();
      helper.addCircle(QGeoCoordinate(47.6, 9.5));
      return app.exec();
  }

  #include "main.moc"
  ```

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.14
  import QtPositioning 5.14
  import QtLocation 5.14

  Map{
      id: map_map
      anchors.centerIn: parent;
      anchors.fill: parent
      plugin: Plugin {
          name: "mapboxgl" // "osm", "esri", ...
      }
      center: QtPositioning.coordinate(47.6,9.5)
      zoomLevel: 8
      Connections{
          target: helper
          onCircleSignal: {
              var component = Qt.createComponent("rect.qml");
              if (component.status === Component.Ready){
                  var o = component.createObject(map_map);
                  o.center = coordinate
                  map_map.addMapItem(o)
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.14
  import QtPositioning 5.14
  import QtLocation 5.14

  Map{
      id: map_map
      anchors.centerIn: parent;
      anchors.fill: parent
      plugin: Plugin {
          name: "mapboxgl" // "osm", "esri", ...
      }
      center: QtPositioning.coordinate(47.6,9.5)
      zoomLevel: 8

      Component{
          id: provider
          MapCircle{
              center{
                  latitude: 47.6
                  longitude: 9.5
              }
              radius: 5000.0
              color: 'green'
              border.width: 3
          }
      }
      function createCirle(map, position){
          var o  = provider.createObject(map)
          o.center = position
          map.addMapItem(o)
          return o
      }

      Connections{
          target: helper
          onCircleSignal: {
              var o = createCirle(map_map, coordinate)
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Use a model with MapItemView:

  ```
  #include <QGuiApplication>
  #include <QQuickView>
  #include <QGeoCoordinate>
  #include <QQmlContext>
  #include <QStandardItemModel>

  int CoordinateRole = Qt::UserRole + 1000;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
      QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
      QQuickView view;
      QStandardItemModel model;
      QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
      roles[CoordinateRole] = QByteArray("coordinate");
      model.setItemRoleNames(roles);
      view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("circle_model", &model);
      view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/map.qml"));
      view.resize(1000, 650);
      view.setTitle("GUI");
      view.show();

      QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
      item->setData(QVariant::fromValue(QGeoCoordinate(47.6, 9.5)), CoordinateRole);
      model.appendRow(item);

      return app.exec();
  }
  ```

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.14
  import QtPositioning 5.14
  import QtLocation 5.14

  Map{
      id: map_map
      anchors.centerIn: parent;
      anchors.fill: parent
      plugin: Plugin {
          name: "mapboxgl" // "osm", "esri", ...
      }
      center: QtPositioning.coordinate(47.6,9.5)
      zoomLevel: 8

      MapItemView{
          model: circle_model
          delegate: MapCircle{
              center: model.coordinate
              radius: 5000.0
              color: 'green'
              border.width: 3
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: thank you for the fast answer! I used the last option you mentioned. Works like a charm

Comment: It's slightly confusing where one alternative starts, and where it ends; E.g the "Use  a model with MapItemView" Is that an alternative or part of the previous alternative?